# Bernstein's Lemma

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

$X_n,Y_n,Z_n$ are all random variables such that, $X_n,Y_n$ has distribution $G_n(x,y)$ and $X_n$ has distribution $F_n(x)$. We also have that
Also,$$Z_n=X_n+Y_n$$
$$Var(Y_n) \to 0\hspace{3mm} as\hspace{3mm} n \to \infty$$

Also, $F_n(x) \xrightarrow{D} F_X(x)$.

Prove:

$Z_n \xrightarrow{D} X $.

My attempt:

$P(Z_n \leq z)= P( X_n+Y_n \leq z)= P(X_n \leq z+ \epsilon, Y_n \leq -\epsilon) \leq P( X_n \leq z+\epsilon)=F_n(z+\epsilon) \\$
$P(Z_n \geq z)= P( X_n +Y_n \geq z)= P(X_n \geq z-\epsilon, Y_n \geq \epsilon)$

I am stuck here, I cannot figure out a way to bring the $Var(Y_n)$ into the picture. Can someone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: You have some unclarified notation. What is $Z$, $X$ and $F(x)$? I also think that using $F_n$ as a notation for two functions simultaneously, is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: I have changed the notations, I hope there's no confusion now.

Comment: It looks like you assume nothing on $Z_n$ right now. Are you missing some assumptions on that sequence?

Comment: Since $Var(Y_n) \to 0$, by Chebyshevs inequality, we can show that $Y_n$ converges in probability to its mean, $E(Y)$. Thus we have $Y_n$ converging in probability and $X_n$ converging in distribution, then we need to show that $X_n+Y_n$ converges in distribution. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example:** $X_n$ all have the same distribution, say standard normal; $Y_n=(-1)^n$ (non-random). Then each $Y_n$ has variance $0$, but the distribution of $Z_n$ alternates between $\mathcal N(1,1)$ and $\mathcal N(-1,1)$, so $(Z_n)$ doesn't converge in distribution.

**A way out:** Assume instead that $Y_n\to 0$ in probability. Then you will have $Z_n \xrightarrow{D} X $, as a consequence of Slutzky's Theorem.